# Scala  Class Variable Name Hides Method Parameter Name 

Tags: scala, variables, parameters

I wonder why I can't use the same name for function parameter and the name used in a class. Please refer to the following example.

```
scala> class Person() {var name = "bob" }
defined class Person

scala> val p = new Person
p: Person = Person@486f8860

scala> p.name
res0: java.lang.String = bob

scala> p.name = "alice"

scala> p.name
res1: java.lang.String = alice

scala> def chngName(name:String) = new Person() {this.name= name}
chngName: (name: String)Person

scala> val p = chngName("aa")
p: Person = $anon$1@3fa1732d

scala> p.name
res2: java.lang.String = bob

scala> def chngName(n:String) = new Person() {name= n}
chngName: (n: String)Person

scala> val p = chngName("aa")
p: Person = $anon$1@19d2052b

scala> p.name
res3: java.lang.String = aa
```

Of course, I can use a different name but I want to why I can't or there is something I am miss here. Thanks

Comment: In your example, you could just define `class Person(var name: String = "bob")` and then write `new Person` to get bob, or `new Person("aa")` for a custom name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Why do want to use `var` when you return a new object in `chngName`?)*

As has been said, the class’s field of the same name shadows the method argument.

You could of course rename it before entering the class’s scope:

```
def chngName(name:String) = {
  val _name = name
  new Person() { name = _name }
}
```

For this use case, there are a few other options, however. It depends, though, whether you want to copy the object, ie. return a `new Person`, or if a simple change of the `var` suffices.

If you want to return a completely new object, you may consider using a `case class` which adds a `copy` method with the same semantics and identically named method arguments. (So you can use named arguments):

```
case class Person(name: String)
val p = Person("bob")
p.name // bob
val q= p.copy(name = "aa")
q.name // aa
q == p // false
```

Answer (score 3):

The block you passed after `new Person()` lies in the `Person` initialization body (it's inside the constructor if you prefer). In this scope `name` is defined as the class field. (so `name` is the same as `this.name`).

Comment: I guess as much. How do I refer to the function parameter name which is outside the scope of the class?

Comment: In initialization block I don't think you can. You'll have to provide a different name. BTW see Jean-Phillipe comment for a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score -1):

this works as intended (although is much less concise)

```
 def chngName(name:String) = {val r = new Person; r.name=name; r;}
```

Comment: It didn't focus on the question.